# What is the amount of non-isomorphic trees of order n with a maximum incidence of 4?

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, trees, chemistry

It's a graph-theory model of the theoretical amount of possible non-cyclic alkanes isomers.

I can't find a way to compute it? Any hints appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want [A000602](https://oeis.org/A000602) which is the count of CnH2n+2 compounds.

Also see [this answer](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/40911/4665) on chemistry stack exchange, which has some interesting background.